# Cross Version EXPDP/IMPDP of Indexes

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, impdp, expdp

Our source database is 11g and target is 19c.

My question is about exporting and importing indexes.

Does the EXPDP command "exports" the actual index structure or just the "Create index" statement which is then executed on target ?

Comment: It only exports the DDL for the index, not the data.

Comment: So really the phrase "exporting the index" which is used very commonly is really a misnomer. Indexes cannot really be "exported" using EXPDP.

Only the instructions on how they can be "rebuilt" on target is exported; which is not same as "exporting the index"

Comment: Correct. There is no mechanism to load data directly into an index. You must either load the table without indexes and then rebuild the indexes, or recreate the indexes on an empty table and then reload the data. Tables are also recreated as "empty" using their defined DDL before having data reloaded by impdp. expdp/impdp is generally a *logical* relocation of data, not a physical relocation of binary constructs unless you're working with transportable tablespaces.